# What is the output type in Bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

In Bazel you can define an attribute type, which could be `int` or `string` ... or `output`

What does it mean to have a type of attribute as `output`?

Here's an example:

```
def _something(ctx):
    print("The username is: ", ctx.attr.username)
    print("boolean value is", ctx.attr.boolean)
    print("my age is:", ctx.attr.age)
    print("Start printing hours .." )
    for i in ctx.attr.hours:
        print (i)
    print("Finish printing hours ..")
    print("Depending on: ", ctx.attr.dep_on)

print_me = rule(
    implementation = _something,
    attrs = {
        "username" : attr.string(),
        "boolean" : attr.bool(),
        "age" : attr.int(),
        "hours" : attr.int_list(),
        "dep_on": attr.label(),
        "the_results": attr.output(),
    },
)
```

It's a simple rule, which has `the_results` as of type output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that attribute corresponds to a file that the rule will create an action to produce. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#output-attributes and https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/attr.html#output.

Comment: I have already read that page. But still didn't get it. In my example, what would be that file "output" please?

Comment: Your rule would have to produce it.

Comment: How could the output of a rule be an input attribute? still didn't get it

Comment: It allows the user to provide a name for an output of the rule. So, `print_me(the_results = 'my_result_file')` will write to `my_result_file`.

Comment: I see, and also what would it write?

Comment: The would be up to your rule. `attr.output` just indicates that the rule has an output that the user can configure the name of.